# What is the simplest way to get array with unique values in JS?

Tags: javascript, set

So i need to get array of unique values. I decided to use SET

here is my function:

```
const getSalesFunnel = (state) => {
    const funnelSteps = new Set()
    Object.entries(state.sales.funnels).forEach(([k, v]) => {
      v.filter((s) => s.salesFunnel).forEach((s) => funnelSteps.add(s))
    })
    console.log('getSalesFunnel -> funnelSteps', funnelSteps)

    return []
  }
```

From docs about SET, it must save only unique values. But in my case, i have set of 6 same values, but they are UNIQUE! What's wrong?

Here is what i got in console.log

[image]

Does this thing checks values? Or it thinks, that returned values from `v.filter` is UNIQUE object  links, so it's add it to set?

Also here is `state.sales.funnels` structure

[image]

Comment: Objects are compared by identity, not content. Two distinct objects are always !== to each other.

Comment: as i guessed:(( i wanted to have elegant way:) ok, i'll use indexOf and remove set from my case.. thx!

Comment: I am not sure how slow this option could be, but a quick way to deduplicate these objects would be to "stringify" them with the properties sorted alphabetically, that way you would end up with the same string 3 times, and then your Set would not allow multiple items. You could also use the ID as unique key.